# Can I run Tensorflow, Keras,and Pytorch for deep learning projects on the latest and highly spec iMac Pro without Nvidia GPUs

Tags: tensorflow

I love my iMac and do not mind paying top dollars for it. However I need to run Tensorflow, Keras, and Pytorch for deep learning projects. Can I run them on the latest and maxed-out spec iMac Pro ?

Comment: Without NVIDIA GPU, the computations will be really slow. You can still use NVIDIA GPU using eGPU though I'm not sure how strong is the support for these. I'd recommend using AWS, GCP or some other cloud platform when you're training the deep learning models.

Comment: **Can you**? Sure. **Should you**, probably open to opinion.

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow 1.8 supports [ROCm](https://rocm.github.io/hardware.html), IDK how it performs next to nvidia's CUDA 
but that means that if you have GPU (radeon) that supports ROCm you can use tensorflow gpu 
running tensorflow on gpu is possible but extremely slow and can be added to the definition of torture